# How to delete the permission level using power shell using CSOM?

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

I need to delete the default permission level in SharePoint site using power shell CSOM.

Like 
 - Full Control
 - contribute 
 - List item
 - edit

Comment: is that are you working on sharepoint online?

Comment: No, I need to run these script on 2013 and latter in 2015 and online as well